# Loading XML in php giving error

Tags: php, xml

I am trying to load xml in php

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load("LoginVal.xml");
```

I am getting an error as

> Warning: domdocument::domdocument() expects at least 1 parameter, 0 given in C:\Program Files\Apache Group\Apache2\htdocs\hello.php on line 5
>
> Fatal error: Call to undefined method domdocument::load() in C:\Program Files\Apache Group\Apache2\htdocs\hello.php on line 7

Regards,
Hemant

Answer (score 1):

Obiviously there is a [parameter missing](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.construct.php) in the constructor. Try something like

```
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'iso-8859-1');
```

Answer (score 0):

The Fatal error is because the object was instantiated the warning is as it says it is expecting a parameter check https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.construct.php

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the comment in [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.construct.php), this looks like a known issue (especially comment #2).

Answer (score 0):

Please read the user-comments in [`DOMDocument::__construct()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.construct.php). There is a talk about exactly this error when using PHP5 on Windows machines (which most likely matches your configuration). I'm quoting [christian dot reinecke at web dot de](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.construct.php#84476):

> [...] make sure you're not
> overwritting this dom library by
> another (f.e. extension=php_domxml.dll
> in php.ini). XAMPP f.e. delivers its
> standard version with php_domxml.dll
> which ends up in this error message

Make sure that there is no `php_domxml.dll`-extension in your `php.ini`.

Answer (score 0):

try the full file path

Yours

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load("LoginVal.xml");
```

Try

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load("/path/to/LoginVal.xml");
```